Int on the $N$-Ball

Let $N \in \Bbb{N}$, $\overline{B}_R(0) = \{ x \in \Bbb{R}^N : \lVert x \rVert \leq R \}$ and $S_R(0) = \{ x \in \Bbb{R}^N : \lVert x \rVert = R \}$ . Then, for all $f \in \mathcal{C} (\overline{B}_R(0) ; \Bbb{R})$ it has: $$\int_{\overline{B}_R(0)} f(x) dx = \int_0^R \int_{S_r(0)} f(x) dS_x dr$$

I am trying to prove this excercise from my Partial's Equation Theory Book but I am quite stuck. My idea first was to use the Gauss Divergence Theorem by searching a vectorial field $F$ whose divergence was $f$ but it is not working. Furthermore, I remember from Measure Theory that the int on a finite union of disjoint sets is the sum of the ints on each set and since $\overline{B}_R(0) = \cup_{0\leq r \leq R} S_r(0)$ is a disjoint union I thought that there should be a way to translate the finite quality to this case, but in my books does not appear, so any possible help would be appreciated.

Define a vectorfield $F$ on $\overline{B}_r(0)$ by
$$
F(x) = \frac{xf(x)}{r}.$$
At any point $x \in S_r(0)$ the outward pointing unit normal vector is $\nu(x) = \dfrac xr$ so that $F(x) \cdot \nu(x) = f(x)$ on $S_r(0)$. On the other hand $$\mathrm{div\,}F = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \frac{x_k f(x)}{r} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{f(x)}{r} + \frac {x_k}r \frac{\partial}{\partial  x_k} f(x) \right) = \frac 1r \left( n f(x) + x \cdot Df(x)\right).$$ The divergence theorem tells you that
$$ \int_{S_r(0)} f(x) dS_x = \int_{S_r(0)} F(x) \cdot \nu(x) dS_x = \frac 1r \int_{B_r(0)} nf(x) + x \cdot Df(x) dx.$$
Now let $\phi(r) = \displaystyle \int_{B_r(0)} f(x) \, dx$. Under the change of variable $x = ry$ this becomes
$$ \phi(r) = \int_{B_1(0)} f(ry) r^n \, dy.$$
Differentiate with respect to $r$. Since $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}f(ry) = y \cdot Df(ry)$ you get
\begin{align} \phi'(r)  &= \int_{B_1(0)} y \cdot Df(ry)r^n + n f(ry) r^{n-1} \, dy \\ &= \int_{B_1(0)} y \cdot Df(ry)r^n \, dy + \frac nr \int_{B_1(0)} f(ry) r^n \, dy
\end{align}
for all $0 < r < R$. Again use the change of variable $x = ry$ to get
$$\int_{B_1(0)} y \cdot Df(ry)r^n \, dy = \frac 1r \int_{B_r(0)} x \cdot Df(x) \, dx$$
and
$$\frac nr \int_{B_1(0)} f(ry) r^n \, dy = \frac nr \int_{B_r(0)} f(x) \, dx$$
so that
$$\phi'(r) = \frac 1r \int_{B_r(0)} nf(x) + x \cdot f(x) \, dx = \int_{S_r(0)} f(x) \, dS_x.$$
Finally, the fundamental theorem of calculus and the calculation above give
$$\int_{B_R(0)} f(x) \, dx = \phi(R) = \int_0^R \phi'(r) \, dr = \int_0^R \int_{S_r(0)} f(x) dS_x dr.$$

Thank you so much! This is perfect
